# Codeigniter method for update

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$age=10;
$id=1;
$sql='update student set age=age+$age where sid=$id;
```

I want to write this sql statement using Codeigniter how is that possible?Any native way in Codeigniter to do this? I am using Codeigniter active record

Comment: try once using `$this->db->set('age', "age+$age", FALSE);`

Comment: Please read more about $this->db->set() method here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this....

```
$this->db->set('age', "age+$age",FALSE);
$this->db->where('sid', $id);
$this->db->update('student');
```

OR

```
$data = array("age"=>"age+$age");
$this->db->set($data);
$this->db->where('sid',$id);
$this->db->update('student');
```

For more see deatais here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data

Comment: $data = array('age'=>'age'+$age);
$this->db->where('sid',$id);
$this->db->update('student',$data); while using this get error.'You must use the "set" method to update an entry.'

Comment: your code generate this query UPDATE `student` SET `age` = 100 WHERE `id` = 19. it does not taking value from table to add the age

Comment: first select age from database then add with $age and set it.OR `$this->db->set('age', "age+$age", FALSE);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132665/discussion-between-reneesh-kurian-and-hikmat-sijapati).

Answer (score 1):

Let me edit my answer

```
$data = array("age"=>"age+$age");
$this->db->set($data);
$this->db->where('sid',$id);
$this->db->update("student",$data);
```

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0 = 'age=age+100' WHERE `id` = 19' at line 1

UPDATE `student` SET 0 = 'age=age+100' WHERE `id` = 19

Comment: I have made changes in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like this:

```
$age = 10;
$id = 1;
$data = array('age' => "age+$age");

$this->db->where('sid',$id);
$this->db->update('student',$data);
```

Using `$this->db->set($data);` can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$data = array(
  "age"=>"age+$age"
);
$this->db->set($data);
$this->db->where('id',$id);
$this->db->update('student');
```

for more info follow https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html